# How to User same Chrome Web Store to host mutliple versions of same Chrome Extension

Tags: versioning, chrome-web-store

I am having Chrome Extension with Version 1.0.0 published to Chrome Web Store and its being actively used by Users. Now I have added some more features to same Chrome Extension and versioning it as 2.0.0. Before I publish to the Users, I wanted it to handover to QA for feature testing. So I wanted to check if I can maintain multiple versions of the Chrome Extensions on Chrome Web Store and then User can pick the version that they wanted to install to their respective browsers.

Or I have to have to separate Chrome Web Store for Production and Non-Production environments?

I checked on https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard and could not figure out if I can maintain multiple versions of the same Extension package.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have multiple versions of your items that are live in the store at the same time, you need to publish it as a separate item.

You can use the name "Name (v2)" for the second item.